# Prove that $h_n \to h$ uniformly in $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Suppose that $m(\lim_{x\to \infty}f_n)=f$ in $[a,b]$. i.e $(f_n)$ is a sequence of integrable functions and $f$ is a Riemann integrable function, such that $(f_n)$ converges in measure to $f$ in [a,b]. If $g$ is Riemann Integrable in $[a,b]$ and we define
>
> $$h(x) = \int_a^xf(t)g(t)dt,$$
> $$ h_n(x) = \int_a^xf_n(t)g(t)dt$$ for $x \in [a,b].$
> Prove that $h_n \to h$ uniformly in $[a,b]$.

I am lost with this problem, and would like to make the homework. Today I read the definition of convergence in measure, and some info that concerns it. Some related theorems, for example.I know the definition of something that converges uniformly to other something, but I have no idea what to do, how to think about this problem, or even what kind of example could serve for me to see what I want to prove, or how would I go about proving the statement.

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f_n\to f(\text{in measure $\mu$})\implies $

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu (\{x\in [a,b]:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon\})=0 \forall \epsilon>0$

Since $g$ is Riemann-Integrable $\implies |g|\le M$

Now $|\int _a^x f_n(t)g(t)-f(t)g(t)|\le \int _a^x|f_n(t)-f(t)||g(t)|\le M \int _a^x|f_n(t)-f(t)|$

Now consider for any $\epsilon >0$;

$A=\{x\in  [a,b]:|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon\}$ and $B=\{x\in [a,b]:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon\}$

$\int _a^x|f_n(t)-f(t)|=\int _{A\cup B} |f_n(t)-f(t)|$

Note that $\mu(B)=0 $ and hence $\int _a^x|f_n(t)-f(t)|<(b-a)\epsilon$

Hence  $|\int _a^x f_n(t)g(t)-f(t)g(t)|<M(b-a)\epsilon$ (converging uniformly)